# Making a graph (asteriks) with Printf on Linux

Tags: linux, graph, printf

I made a little program where I see the date, time and donwload speed every time in 10 sec. Before I made my program I installed speedtest-cli.

Now follows a code block:

```
 !/bin/bash
 while [ True ]
 do

 sleep 1 
 date=$(date "+%D +%T)
 dlspeed=$(speedtest-cli --simple | egrep 'Download')
 echo $date > bandwidth 
 echo $dlspeed >> bandwidth
 content=$(cat bandwidth | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/;\n/;/g')
 echo $content >> output
 done
```

When we run the program everything works nice. The first ouput is 14/12/2016 18:33:25 Download: 8.33 Mbits. Every 10 sec it shows me my download speed.   I am using here a loop.

Now I need to use printf to make an graph based on the Download speed.So the output has to be 14/12/2016 18:33:25 Download: 8.33 Mbits ********.

My question. How to make this graph with asterisks and add them.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Print $x asterisks?

Comment: I updated my question. I hope you can understand me now better.

Comment: Not much, as I don't have the `speedtest` you use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop in bash:

```
for i in {1..6} ; do
    printf '*'
done
```

For a variable, you can use `seq` instead of curly brackets:

```
n=6
for i in $(seq $n) ; do
    printf '*'
done
```

Comment: Thanks, seq helped me a lot.